# Stop Task Bar Apps from flashing

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar, flashing

when an application is minimized but running, and something happens inside of the application, it's task bar icon starts to flash orange.
I.E. Teams recieves a message, a browser download is complete. I would like to get rid of this flashing as much as possible.

So far I tried:

1. Change Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundFlashCount to Hex 0, Hex 1, Dec 0 and Dec 1
2. Change Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundLockTimeout to Hex 0, Hex 1, Dec 0 and Dec 1
3. Change Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundFlashCount to Hex 0, Hex 1, Dec 0 and Dec 1
4. Change Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundLockTimeout to Hex 0, Hex 1, Dec 0 and Dec 1

Changing the key to Dec did not seem to work, it always remained Hex.

None of this did work: After reboot, at first it seems to work for a couple of minutes, but after a while, Apps start to flash.

Any more ideas what I could try?

Comment: `Dec`/`Hex` changes only how the data is displayed. The value itself doesn't change. For values lesser than 10 dec and hex will be the same.

Comment: I think 7+ Taskbar tweaker can disable this.

Comment: Those are just normal notifications (like the Notification icon) to tell you an app needs attention. Keep current on your app activity and the flashing will stop (native Windows without registry changes).

Comment: @John, I wish that would work! At least MS Teams also wants to be in the FOKUS so it doesnt flash.

Comment: @LPChip, thanks for the hint, will check that out!

Comment: There are two reasons a taskbar button will flash. 1. The program attempts to become the foreground window when it doesn't have that right. Windows denies it and flashes its' taskbar button. This is for older programs. This is the settings you played with. 2. Programs that are newer will not attempt to set themselves as the foreground window but will explicitly flash the taskbar button. There are no Windows' settings for this but may be application settings.